# wcf adding issue?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm working with N-tier architecture. I have a WCF service in a hosting layer. I added services file successfully in here.

Problem is when I add the service in an application. It adds the service to the project successfully, but when I call the service I can't call it from my application class but when I rebuild project I haven't any issue.

On the other hand if I add the same service to another project I haven't a problem and everything is ok.

Has anyone encountered this?

```
 <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="true" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:5555/MyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="ServiceReference1.IMyService"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: can you put your exception here?

Comment: Compare the bindings to one of your projects that works. Is the endpoint URL the same? Is your service actually part of your application solution or do you run it up separately?

Comment: Thanks for your interesting, I solved the problem